# How to return result from python script to shell script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, sh

I have a python script `a.py` which is run by a shell script `b.sh`. I wish to return the result (which is int) of `a.py` to `b.sh`.

I know I can use `sys.exit(result)` in `a.py`. But as I wrote `set -ex` in `b.sh`, the shell script stops after running `a.py`. I don't wish to use `print(result)` eather because I wish to print other information in `a.py`.

Is there any other way to return result from `a.py` to `b.sh`?

Comment: you could print to another stream than STDOUT and b could read from it

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk How to print to another stream and how can b read from it?

Comment: https://dev.to/0xbf/use-mkfifo-to-create-named-pipe-linux-tips-5bbk

Comment: Don't use `set -e`.

Comment: You can of course invoke your script as `a.py||false`, but what's the point in returning a certain exit code, if you don't want to evaluate it?

Comment: You can't return anything from the script. You can either write to a file, or set the integer exit code (which is for signaling success or various kinds of errors, not for passing data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
{ a.py; result=$?; } || true
# the result of a.py is in $result
```

`|| true` temporarily disables `set -e`, and the `$?` special variable gets stored to `$result` before it gets overwritten by the next command.

The downside is that, if your script actually fails (e.g. by raising an exception), you won't notice that. A more robust solution would be to print the needed result and catch it as output, and print the other output to the standard error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), that the exit codes should not be used for integer passing.
Why not passing output of the python-file via stdout?

```bash
value="$(python foo.py)"
echo "${value}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the integer value to a file. I completely agree that exit codes should not be used for passing any information, other than success or failure of the program.

For example ***b.sh***:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
set -ex

# Create temp file, ensure it is erased on bash script exit
tempfile="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm -f "$tempfile"' EXIT
trap 'exit 1' HUP INT QUIT PIPE TERM

# Run program and write value to temp file
python3 ./a.py -o "$tempfile"

# Read value from temp file
myvalue="$(cat "$tempfile")"

echo "Value from a.py was: $myvalue"
```

And ***a.py***:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
from pathlib import Path

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-o",
    "--output-file",
    help="Write integer value to text file",
    type=str,
    required=True,
)
args = parser.parse_args()

my_value = 42
Path(args.output_file).write_text(str(my_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the exit code from the python script and look it up (and reassign to another variable if necessary)  in the shell script via `$?`:

foo.py:

```
import sys
sys.exit(35)
```

foo.sh:

```
python foo.py
echo $?
```

Run the scripts:

```
> sh foo.sh
35
```

Comment: Please note the OP sets `set -ex` in the shell script.

Comment: Don't abuse exit codes for passing integer data.

Comment: @chapter Why do you call it abuse?